# Can SoapUI's property expansion be used to access a TestCase label?

Tags: soap, soapui

I'm trying to write a SoapUI TestCase at the moment. I'd like to access the label of the test case in one of my test steps. Is there any way to do this using the property expansion syntax?

Something in the region of

${#TestCase#label}

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible using the follow syntax:

```
${=context.testCase.name}
```

**Explanation**

[`${= }`](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html#2-Dynamic-Properties) this allows to execute some *Groovy* code inside the request.

Like in the *Groovy* testSteps you've `context` available so you can access the `testCase` and then access the `name` property which contains the label.